# Having troubles with doubles

Tags: java, double

after long hard work, I have finally completed (almost) my java menu program. However, I am having trouble getting my return change function to work at the end of my code. It is giving very odd numbers. Any ideas?

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaBurger
{
    public static double amountowed = 0;
    public static double amount;
    public static double amount1 = 0;
    public static double amount2 = 0;
    public static double amount3 = 0;
    public static double amount4 = 0;
    public static double amount5 = 0;
    public static double amount6 = 0;
    public static double amount7 = 0;
    public static double amount8 = 0;
    public static double amount9 = 0;
    public static double amount10 = 0;


    static ArrayList MenuItems = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputStreamReader inp = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        int nOption  = 0;
    DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("###.##");


        try
        {
            inp = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            input = new BufferedReader(inp);
            while(true)
            {
        System.out.println("Choose a Menu Option");
                System.out.println("1. Burger - 13.49");
                System.out.println("2. Pasta - 16.79");
                System.out.println("3. Salad - 13.49");
                System.out.println("4. Salmon - 18.99");
                System.out.println("5. Chicken - 16.99");
                System.out.println("6. Nachos - 13.99");
        System.out.println("7. Soup - 6.99");
        System.out.println("8. Fajitas - 18.49");
        System.out.println("9. Ribs - 23.99");
        System.out.println("10. Calamari-9.99");
        System.out.println("11. Clear Order");
        System.out.println("12. Finish Order");
                System.out.println("\nChoose an option(1-12) >> ");
        System.out.println("Subtotal: $" + x.format(amount));
        System.out.println("Total: $" + x.format(amount * 1.13));
        System.out.println("For error correction, choose an option and enter a negative value to void the item.");

                nOption = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

                switch(nOption)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Burger(input);
                        break;
            case 2:
                        Pasta(input);
                        break;
            case 3:
                        Salad(input);
                        break;
            case 4:
                        Salmon(input);
                        break;
            case 5:
                        Chicken(input);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Nachos(input);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Soup(input);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Fajitas(input);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        Ribs(input);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        Calamari(input);
                        break;
            case 11:
            Clear(input);
            break;
            case 12:
            Finish(input);
            break;

                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
        }
    }

    private static void Burger(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many Burgers would you like? ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double aaa = Math.pow(1 + a, a);
            amount1 = (a * 13.49);
        amount += amount1;


                break;
        }
    }

     private static void Pasta(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Pasta would you like? ");
        int b = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double bbb = Math.pow(1 + b, b);
            amount2 = (bbb * 16.79);
        amount += amount2;


                break;
        }
    } private static void Salad(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many Salads would you like? ");
        int c = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double ccc = Math.pow(1 + c, c);
            amount3 = (ccc * 13.49);
        amount += amount3;


                break;
        }
    } private static void Salmon(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Salmon would you like? ");
        int d = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double ddd = Math.pow(1 + d, d);
            amount4 = (ddd * 18.99);
        amount += amount4;


                break;
        }
    } private static void Chicken(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Chicken would you like? ");
        int e = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double eee = Math.pow(1 + e, e);
            amount5 = (eee * 16.99);
        amount += amount5;


                break;
        }
    } private static void Nachos(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Nachos would you like? ");
        int f = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double fff = Math.pow(1 + f, f);
            amount6 = (fff * 13.99);
        amount += amount6;

                break;
        }
    } private static void Soup(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Soup would you like? ");
        int g = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double ggg = Math.pow(1 + g, g);
            amount7 = (ggg * 6.99);
        amount += amount7;

                break;
        }
    } private static void Fajitas(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of 2 Fajitas would you like? ");
        int h = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double hhh = Math.pow(1 + h, h);
            amount8 = (hhh * 18.49);
        amount += amount8;

                break;
        }
    } private static void Ribs(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many racks of Ribs would you like? ");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double iii = Math.pow(1 + i, i);
            amount9 = (iii * 23.99);
        amount += amount9;

                break;
        }
    } private static void Calamari(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

        while(true)
        {

            System.out.println("How many orders of Calamari would you like? ");
        int j = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        double jjj = Math.pow(1 + j, j);
            amount10 = (jjj * 9.99);
        amount += amount10;

                break;
        }
    } private static void Clear(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

    while(true)
    {

        amount = 0;

        break;
    }
    } private static void Finish(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
    {

    while(true)
    {

        DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        System.out.println("Amount Due");
        System.out.println("**********");
        System.out.println("Subtotal:" + x.format(amount));
        System.out.println("Total:" + x.format(amount * 1.13));
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount tendered");
        int k = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        double kk = Math.pow(1 + k, k);
        amountowed = ((amount * 1.13) - kk);
        if(amountowed == 0)
        {
        System.out.println("Thanks for paying with exact change!");
        System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(amountowed < 0)
        {
        System.out.println("Change due:" + x.format(amountowed * -1.00));
        System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Amount still owed:" + x.format(amountowed * -1.00));
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Choose a Menu Option
1. Burger - 13.49
2. Pasta - 16.79
3. Salad - 13.49
4. Salmon - 18.99
5. Chicken - 16.99
6. Nachos - 13.99
7. Soup - 6.99
8. Fajitas - 18.49
9. Ribs - 23.99
10. Calamari-9.99
11. Clear Order
12. Finish Order

Choose an option(1-12) >>
Subtotal: $0
Total: $0
For error correction, choose an option and enter a negative value to void the it
em.
1
How many Burgers would you like?
1
Choose a Menu Option
1. Burger - 13.49
2. Pasta - 16.79
3. Salad - 13.49
4. Salmon - 18.99
5. Chicken - 16.99
6. Nachos - 13.99
7. Soup - 6.99
8. Fajitas - 18.49
9. Ribs - 23.99
10. Calamari-9.99
11. Clear Order
12. Finish Order

Choose an option(1-12) >>
Subtotal: $13.49
Total: $15.24
For error correction, choose an option and enter a negative value to void the it
em.
12
Amount Due
**********
Subtotal:13.49
Total:15.24
Please enter the amount tendered
100
Change due:270481382942152600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Why am I getting wacky numbers for the change due?

Comment: How do I implement that into my code? I am not very good at programming..this took me over a month to do, it's only my first year coding.

Comment: It is not floating point rounding error, because for simple calculations involving double that would give answers within about one part in 10^15 of the correct answer, not completely wild answers.

Comment: @Zutty How would this help in this case?  BTW In the interest of balance, I always recommend people use `double` for money. ;)

Comment: @user1965245 As a general rule try to cut the problem down to its bare minimum before posting it on SO. Often if you cut the program down to the bare minimum that exibits the problem you will actually find the solution yourself (leading to you being a better programmer) or at the very least the people on SO will be much happier to help. For example does the error only occure if you have all 10 menu items, if not cut it down to 1, do you need the keyboard input or would the error still occure if the main method just ran through a premade series of commands

Comment: +1 for a rhyming question.

Comment: My mistake. I thought I saw a decimal point in the output. I apologise for misleading you user1965245.

Comment: @user1965245  why you are doing int k = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        double kk = Math.pow(1 + k, k); this. can u explain  me. I am not getting you

Comment: @nagarajub it was the OP's attempt to convert a number to double, don't ask

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well... Is the following line needed here?

```
double kk = Math.pow(1 + k, k);
```

It completely messed up change computation, since you powered what the user inputs (k) + 1 to the kth power.

If you want to change it to a double, `(double)k` will do. Of course, for monetary computation, you'd better be using:

1. BigDecimal
2. cent based `Integer` / `Long` computation

Comment: That changes it into a double so I can get decimals in the change

Comment: @user1965245 in your example this computes `1010000000000`(and another 90 `0`s)

Comment: I would be facinated to know what you *thought* double kk = Math.pow(1 + k, k) did

Comment: Have you tested it for a non-integer tendered amount, such as 1.50?

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling to see why you're over-complicating your change computation so much.. Can't you simply compute `amount tendered - total`?

Comment: I had to convert amount tendered to a double first or else it gave me errors

Comment: `total` is of type double. Arithmetic promotion should have implicitly converted `amount tendered` to a double.

Comment: you can convert something to double by casting to double: (double). I agree that it shouldn't be nessissary, but if it is this is the simple way to do it.

Comment: Agreed, but why explicitly cast, when it will be done for you at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

```
 int e = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
 double eee = Math.pow(1 + e, e);
```

Let's say I want 5 things.

```
 double eee = Math.pow(1 + 5, 5)
```

This is 6 * 6 * 6 * 6 * 6 (i.e. a very big number).  I think you just want a simple multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a double from a string, use Double.parseDouble instead of Integer.parseInt. Do not do the extra pow calculation, that is making your results completely wrong.

More generally, throwing in random lines of code is rarely a good approach to compiler error reports. It is much better to understand what is going on, and deliberately fix that problem.

At some point, you will probably actually encounter floating point rounding error, and will again be advised to use BigDecimal instead of double.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first ...

> 1. you dont need unneccessary while loops (Fixed in below code )
> 2. Math.pow(1 + a, a) not required.(Fixed in below code )
> 3. amount1 , amount 2 etc can be declared as Local variable (NOT Fixed in below code ) as it dont harm

```
private static void Burger(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("How many Burgers would you like? ");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
  //  double aaa = Math.pow(1 + a, a);// Why THis??? 
  amount1 = ((double)a * 13.49);
    amount += amount1;

}

 private static void Pasta(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("How many orders of Pasta would you like? ");
    int b = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

   // double bbb = Math.pow(1 + b, b); You dont need this 
    amount2 = ((double)b * 16.79);
    amount += amount2;

} 
private static void Salad(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("How many Salads would you like? ");
    int c = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    //double ccc = Math.pow(1 + c, c); No Need of this again 
        amount3 = ((double)c * 13.49);
    amount += amount3;

    }
} private static void Salmon(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{

    System.out.println("How many orders of Salmon would you like? ");
    int d = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    //double ddd = Math.pow(1 + d, d); No Need
    amount4 = ((double)d * 18.99);
    amount += amount4;
}
 private static void Chicken(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
 {

    System.out.println("How many orders of Chicken would you like? ");
    int e = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
    amount5 = ((double)e * 16.99);
    amount += amount5;

}
 private static void Nachos(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{

    System.out.println("How many orders of Nachos would you like? ");
    int f = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    amount6 = ((double)f * 13.99);
    amount += amount6;

}
 private static void Soup(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("How many orders of Soup would you like? ");
    int g = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    amount7 = ((double)g * 6.99);
    amount += amount7;

}
 private static void Fajitas(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("How many orders of 2 Fajitas would you like? ");
    int h = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
     amount8 = ((double)h * 18.49);
    amount += amount8;

}
private static void Ribs(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("How many racks of Ribs would you like? ");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
     amount9 = ((double)i * 23.99);
    amount += amount9;

}
 private static void Calamari(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{

    System.out.println("How many orders of Calamari would you like? ");
    int j = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    amount10 = ((double)j * 9.99);
    amount += amount10;

}
 private static void Clear(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{
    amount = 0;

}
private static void Finish(BufferedReader input) throws IOException
{
amountowed =amount * 1.13
DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

while(amountowed >0)
{
    System.out.println("Amount Due");
    System.out.println("**********");
    System.out.println("Subtotal:" + x.format(amount));
    System.out.println("Total:" + x.format(amountowed));
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount tendered");
    double k = Double.parseDouble(input.readLine());
   // double kk = Math.pow(1 + k, k); No Need
    amountowed = (amountowed  - k);
    if(amountowed == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Thanks for paying with exact change!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(amountowed < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Change due:" + x.format(amountowed * -1.00));
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Amount still owed:" + x.format(amountowed));
    }

    }
}
```